# how to know that October 2012 starts with monday in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to this Objective C. I'm trying to do an Calendar application.

Could anyone please let me know how to know on which day the month starts? (Suppose, for example, October 2012 month starts on Monday and November 2012 starts on Thursday. Like that how to know the start day of September 2014?).

Also please let me know how to get the start day (Monday or tuesday...) of the month based on the month.

Comment: Looking in the [Date and Time Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html) would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];

//-- get our date from a string representation
NSDate *date2 = [formatter dateFromString:@"2014-09-01 00:00:00"];

//-- convert it so to extract the full day name
[formatter setDateFormat:@"cccc"];
NSString *result = [formatter stringFromDate:date2];
```